# onReceive() method is not called in a Fragment

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, fragment

I have an Activity and 2 fragments.The Activity has a BottomNavigationView which holds 2 items(Fragments).In the first fragment the user inputs data through EditText and on button click I send a **Localbroadcast** which contains the user input.But when I try to receive it in the Second Fragment, it simply is not retrieved. But when I try to retrieve it in the 1st fragment I get the data.The **BroadcastReceiver** is registered dynamically in **onCreateView** of 2nd fragment. Can anyone help me with this problem?This is really bugging me..Expecting your help

Fragment1:

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                input = user_input.getText().toString();
                if (input.trim().length() != 0 && !TextUtils.isEmpty(input)) {
                    Log.e("data",input);
                    Intent intent = new Intent("send");
                    intent.putExtra("sms", input);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

                }
```

Fragment2:

```
 if (smsreceiver==null)
        {
            smsreceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    Log.e("Retreive","Retrieve");
                }
            };
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(smsreceiver,new IntentFilter("send"));
        }
```

Log:

```
09-04 14:45:51.007 14829-14829/com.globemaster.com.messageapp E/data: cxs
09-04 14:45:51.857 14829-14829/com.globemaster.com.messageapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
09-04 14:45:51.937 14829-14829/com.globemaster.com.messageapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
09-04 14:45:51.977 14829-14829/com.globemaster.com.messageapp E/OnCreateView: Called
09-04 14:45:51.977 14829-14829/com.globemaster.com.messageapp D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
09-04 14:45:52.047 14829-14829/com.globemaster.com.messageapp E/Started: Called
09-04 14:45:52.047 14829-14829/com.globemaster.com.messageapp E/Onresume: called
09-04 14:45:52.077 14829-14829/com.globemaster.com.messageapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Comment: Can you post the logs ? Are you sure that your log "data" is displayed ?

Comment: Log.e("Retreive","Retrieve"); in the onReceive in SecondFragment is not called. I did not give any other log

Comment: @Maxouille I posted the logs

Comment: Okay so it means that your `Log.e("data",input);` is not called ! So `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);` is not called, that's why you don't receive the broadcast in the second fragment. What is the content of your EditText when you click on send ?

Comment: No data is called.See inn the logs above."cxs" is the data I sent recently.

Comment: Hello...Are u still there?

Comment: First of all, I don't think you need this : `input.trim().length() != 0`. TextUtils will make the job. Then, the user input is a text that the user has to type in the EditText. If you don't write anything in the EditText, your broadcast will not be triggered ! Try to  remove the input.trim and write something in the edittext before clicking on send

Comment: I tried as you suggested.I am still not getting the data in the second frag.When I tried to access it on onReceive method in first fragment itself,it worked.Why is it that I can retrieve data in the first frag and not second frag?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179370/discussion-between-maxouille-and-jobin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the right way to use Broadcast. You cannot receive the broadcast as the second fragment is not started yet. You should change to the second fragment when you click on the send button with the sms text as argument.

Try this. It works for me :

FirstFragment.java

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                input = user_input.getText().toString();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(input)) {
                    Log.d("SendFrag", "sending : "+input);
                    // Set data into fragment
                    ReceiveSmsFragment fragment = new ReceiveSmsFragment();
                    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                    arguments.putString("sms", input);
                    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                    // Change fragment with argument
                    FragmentTransaction transaction=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragcontainer, fragment);
                    transaction.commit();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please enter a valid input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                input = null;
            }
        });
```

And SecondFragment.java

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("OnCreateView","Called");

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.receive_sms_frag, container, false);

        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        String sms_string = arguments.getString("sms");
        if (sms == null) {
                    sms = new Sms();
        }
        sms.add(sms_string);
        Log.d("ReceiveFrag", "received : "+sms_string);

        return view;

    }
```

Finally, your sms class was weird. I post here a better version 
Sms.java

```
public class Sms {
    private static ArrayList<String> sms_list;
    // Sms constructor with no private/public, it's a constructor !
    Sms()
    {
        sms_list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(String sms)
    {

        sms_list.add(sms);
    }
    public String get(int position)
    {
        return sms_list.get(position);
    }
    public static int getListLength()
    {
        return sms_list.size();
    }
}
```

Try this and tell me if it's working :)

Hope it helped.

Comment: I was trying to use Sms as a Singleton.

Comment: Oh okay, try your way, that was just to simplify :)
Does it works for you ?

Comment: Yes it works..But I also tried to send broadcast from fragment and receive it in MainActivity.That works too.I will upvote ur answer...

Comment: Thx ! :) Enjoy broadcasts :p